# npm ERR! How to install compiler-sfc that meets peer dependency with vue@2.6.14?

Tags: vue.js, npm, laravel-mix, vue-loader, peer-dependencies

My packageJSON

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.11",
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "install": "^0.13.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.19",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "postcss": "^8.3.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.3",
        "sass": "^1.34.1",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.14",
        "vue-izitoast": "^1.2.1",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.5",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
    }
```

When I check the `npm list vue`

```
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY vue@2.6.14

npm ERR! peer dep missing: vue@3.0.11, required by @vue/compiler-sfc@3.0.11
```

How to install `compiler-sfc` that meets peer dependency with `vue@2.6.14`? I don't want to update vue to 3.

Comment: there's no vue version 2.6.14, do you want to use Vue 3?

Comment: Then, why my npm list vue is showing vue@2.6.14? is there any version that matches 2.5.17?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim What do you mean? [2.6.14 was released yesterday](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases/tag/v2.6.14).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a little bit like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378), because the `@vue/compiler-sfc` package was created for use with Vue 3, and like the error says, [has Vue 3 as a peer dependency](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/9a5bdb15df454fe99b4f695c85a2890d3e059b68/packages/compiler-sfc/package.json#L33-L35).

This means it's incompatible with Vue 2, so you can't use it without upgrading to Vue 3.

The bigger question is– why do you think you need this package?
`@vue/compiler-sfc` is a pack of "lower level utilities for compiling Vue Single File Components":

> This package contains lower level utilities that you can use if you are writing a plugin / transform for a bundler or module system that compiles Vue Single File Components (SFCs) into JavaScript. It is used in vue-loader, rollup-plugin-vue and vite.

Based on your given package list, I don't think you're writing a bundler or module system, so my advice would be to just ditch this dependency.

Comment: Exactly, I am thinking it would be a solution for my problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My actual problem was with the `markdown-it-prism package` import. After importing, `npm run watch` leads to errors. I will create a new question later.